# How the datas are connected to the specific user ID?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-profiles

I'm new to Django and python. I've done login forms but I need to know. How can I connect the contents of the page with the user. 
For example: It's a Q&A site. When you logged in, It shows profile page with the questions that user asked before. How the datas are linked to the specific user ID in the model?
Can it be done using the User object? If so, could you give me some simple example with the script?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some examples of the code you have written so far? What are you trying to achieve with this application?

Comment: It can be done using ForeignKey field that will point to User object. It's too basic thing, I'd recommend you read the docs, like [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/overview/) and [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that "belongs" to a user, should either have a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` (depending on whether the object is owned by one user or many) to `User` on it. Then you can either filter the model based on the `User`:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(user=some_user)
# where `user` is the name of your foreign key field
```

Or you can access the model *through* the user via reverse relations, for example:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

# Later ...

some_user.somemodel_set.all()
```

The second method is more typical since you generally have the user already from the request, so in your view, you'd just do:

```
somemodels = request.user.somemodel_set.all()
```

To get all the `SomeModel`s that belong to the currently logged-in user.

Comment: Thank you Chris Pratt. This is exactly what I need.